# Python invalid syntax in Windows command line

Tags: python

Upon loading up Windows CMD and keying in "python" to enter Python Shell

When I type the following (on my keyboard, line by line)

```
>>> for i in range(2):
...     print(i)
...
```

I get the expected output

```
0
1
```

but when I type the following on my keyboard, again line by line

```
>>> for i in range(2):
...     print(i)
... for i in range(2):
```

when I hit Enter after the second `for` line, I got the following error

```
>>> for i in range(2):
...     print(i)
... for i in range(2):
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    for i in range(2):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's happening? I have been stuck at trying to get this to work for over an hours...

Comment: At the end of your loop, in the python console, you need to press enter (input a blank line) to indicate that the indented block is finished. When you have a `>>>` prompt again, it's ready for your next command.

Comment: if the line starts with `...` its expecting indentation

Answer (score 2):

You have to click enter again after first loop like this

```
>>> for i in range(2):
...     print(i)
...
0
1
>>> for i in range(2):
...     print(i)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to type RETURN a second time. The Python interpreter is waiting for you to finish the command block, as you can see from the `...` prompt before your second `for`.